# Primal-Dual Simplex Algorithm

Tags: linear-programming, reference-request, duality, books, primal-simplex

Are there any recommended textbooks or notes to learn the details about the primal-dual simplex algorithm?

Comment: When I taught the primal-dual algorithm, I used Chapter 5 of Papadimitriou and Steiglitz's *Combinatorial Optimization, Algorithms, and Complexity* as a reference. Unfortunately, a few years after I left UIUC, they reorganized the faculty websites and I can no longer link to my lecture notes.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, thanks Misha for this info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To learn primal-dual simplex method, I have a recommend tutorial video and textbook as following:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Txqky3l2cwc
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4p7JZPg89Q
3. Bazaraa, M. S., Jarvis, J. J., & Sherali, H. D. (2011). Linear programming and network flows. John Wiley & Sons.

The knowledge for basic simplex method, there are two well-known operations research / linear programming books:

1. Hillier, F. S. (2001). Introduction to operations research. McGrawHill.
2. Vanderbei, R. J. (2020). Linear programming. Springer International Publishing.